# From in the message appearing wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

How do I make the email of who sent it from appear? Currently, when the person sends the email, it appears that the person who sent the email was the person who received it

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
      user: "***********@gmail.com",
      pass: "********",
    },
  });
  const message = {
    from: `${request.body.name} <${request.body.email}>`,
    to: "**********@gmail.com",
    cc: request.body.email,
    subject: request.body.subject,
    html: `Message`,
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send an email on behalf of the user without having access to his account, setting the `from` field will not change the fact that you are the sender. To try and see the difference, send the email from the account you used for the `trasporter`, to another account of yours.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
      user: "yourFirstEmail@gmail.com",
      pass: "********",
    },
  });
  const message = {
    from: "yourFirstEmail@gmail.com"`,
    to: "yourSecondEmail@gmail.com",
    cc: request.body.email,
    subject: request.body.subject,
    html: `Message`,
  };
```

This should work.

Comment: Any way to send email without authentication?